# How can I run cscope to search source code in an arbitrary location only and write the cross-reference files in another arbitrary location?

Tags: cscope

This is how my source code directory looks like.

```
learner@centos:~/lab$ tree
.
+-- cscope.out
+-- src
¦   +-- bar
¦   ¦   +-- bar.c
¦   ¦   +-- baz
¦   ¦       +-- baz.c
¦   +-- foo.c
¦   +-- qux
¦       +-- qux.c
+-- work
```

I want to create cross-reference for source code files in an arbitrary location on the filesystem (`~/lab/src/bar` in this example) and write the cross-reference to any arbitrary location (`~/lab/work/cscope.out`) in this case.

Nothing apart from `~/lab/src/bar` should be included in the cross-reference.

The following command, of course, did not work. It includes `~/lab/src/*.c` and `~/lab/src/qux/*.c` also in the cross-reference

```
learner@centos:~/lab$ cscope -b -R -f ~/lab/work/cscope.out
learner@centos:~/lab$ grep "@.*src" ~/lab/work/cscope.out
        @src/bar/bar.c
        @src/bar/baz/baz.c
        @src/foo.c
        @src/qux/qux.c
```

The following command also suffers from the same problem because searching the current directory is automatically implied by default.

```
learner@centos:~/lab$ rm ~/lab/work/cscope.out
learner@centos:~/lab$ cscope -b -R -f ~/lab/work/cscope.out -s ~/lab/src/bar
learner@centos:~/lab$ grep "@.*src" ~/lab/work/cscope.out
        @/home/learner/lab/src/bar/bar.c
        @/home/learner/lab/src/bar/baz/baz.c
        @src/bar/bar.c
        @src/bar/baz/baz.c
        @src/foo.c
        @src/qux/qux.c
```

The following command does not work.

```
learner@centos:~/lab$ rm ~/lab/work/*
learner@centos:~/lab$ cscope -b -R -f ~/lab/work/cscope.out ~/lab/src/bar
Cannot open file /home/learner/lab/src/bar
```

With ctags, a similar command works fine.

```
learner@centos:~/lab$ ctags -R -f ~/lab/work/tags ~/lab/src/bar
learner@centos:~/lab$ grep src ~/lab/work/tags
bar     /home/learner/lab/src/bar/bar.c  /^void bar()$/;"        f
baz     /home/learner/lab/src/bar/baz/baz.c      /^void baz()$/;"        f
main    /home/learner/lab/src/bar/bar.c  /^int main()$/;"        f
main    /home/learner/lab/src/bar/baz/baz.c      /^int main()$/;"        f
```

How can I do the same thing with cscope?

The only workaround I have found so far is to first change into an empty directory and then run the cscope command with `-s ~/lab/src/bar`. This would search the specified directory along with the current directory but since the current directory is empty, only files from the specified directory would be included in the cross-reference.

```
learner@centos:~/lab$ rm ~/lab/work/*
learner@centos:~/lab$ cd ~/lab/work
learner@centos:~/lab/work$ cscope -b -R -f ~/lab/work/cscope.out -s ~/lab/src/bar
learner@centos:~/lab/work$ grep "@.*src" ~/lab/work/cscope.out
        @/home/learner/lab/src/bar/bar.c
        @/home/learner/lab/src/bar/baz/baz.c
```

Is there another solution that won't require me to change the current directory to an empty directory?

Note: The solution should work for a general use-case.

- There may be hundreds of other files and directories that must not be included in the cross-reference (like `foo.c` and `qux` in the above example).
- There may be files with other extension names such as `.h`, `.l`, `.y`, etc. that need to be cross-referenced.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

the trick here is knowing the cscope will also accept a list a sources files rather than searching on its own. So passing the list of files is the problem to solve.

find to the rescue.

```
cscope -b -f <path_to_refdir>/cscope.out `find <path_of_desired_src_tree> -name *.[chly]`
```

in your case

```
cscope -b -f work/cscope.out `find src/bar -name *.[chly]`
```